# Insert code into the head of every page on the website using Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

I have a website that has over 100 separate pages.  Somehow in my ignorance I removed some code from the head of each page that controls the responsive behavior.  I need to reinsert that code in every page, but I can't figure out a way to do that with all pages at once.

I'm using Dreamweaver CS4 (I know, ancient).  Is there a way to insert a line of code into every page?

Comment: some kind of find and replace tool in Dreamweaver ? Find something common for all the pages and add to it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about finding a common code and adding to it.  I was trying to add new code into blank space but this will work.  Thanks.